# Excel Looping through cells with vbTextCompare to assign categories

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, text-comparison

I have a spreadsheet which contains a summary Column(Column K) on each row. I need to match certain words in the summary column in order to assign a category name in a new column(Column V).

I tried doing this with a normal excel If statement but I have sinc efound out there is a limit. So now I'm trying to use the following VBA code.

```
Public Function getCategory()

V_End_Of_Table = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'count the number of rows used'

Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & V_End_Of_Table) 'loop through each row until end of table'


 If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Nationalities", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Range("V" & V_End_Of_Table).Value = "Nationalities"
Else
    Range("V" & V_End_Of_Table).Value = "No Match Found"
End If

Next 'move onto next cell'

End Function
```

So I'm trying to loop through each row, match the text and assign the value. As it stands at the moment I just get #VALUE! returned. 
If I change

Range("V" & V_End_Of_Table).Value

to

MsgBox

it will return the correct string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this bro:

```
For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & V_End_Of_Table)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Nationalities", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Range("V" & cell.Row).Value = "Nationalities"
    Else
        Range("V" & cell.Row).Value = "No Match Found"
    End If
Next
```

instead of `InStr` you could use `StrComp` function to compare 2 words